# How to answer "why did you leave your last job?" if you left because of retaliation after going to HR?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, resignation, human-resources, employment

I have an interview this week with my dream company and I don't want to seem like a risky hire.  How do I frame leaving my last job with a different tech company due to retaliation by my manager after a substantiated claim to HR of bullying and harassment?  This was a unique situation and I have never had issues with employers nor have I gone to HR for any reason before.

Comment: I am looking for better opportunities. This works all the time.

Answer (score 16):

**I am in search of new opportunities to grow and new challenges.**

This is one of many interview questions where there is a correct and standard answer and giving any other answer rarely makes sense.

Comment: Sounds interesting, why couldn't you do that at your current employer?

Comment: Good point, so have an answer for that.  One which is aimed at the target company's needs, environment, culture and oh-so-specialness.

Comment: A decent interviewer will spot a standard answer like this a mile off.

Answer (score 4):

"I must say that I value [former employer] a lot because of [true compliment], [true compliment] and [true compliment]. But, at least in the department I worked in, I personally perceived the climate as, for a lack of a better word, hostile. It was an interesting experience, certainly different from any company I have ever worked before. But it was also an experience I would not want to repeat. "

Then change topic - perhaps by stating that you have noticed the good climate at [the company you are applying to] and giving an example.

If they insist to learn more: Stay polite regarding your former employer, do not dwell on it too much.